# How can I update a specific tuple in a list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I'm a beginner is Haskell and I'm trying to make a function which can give a raise to the salary of a person with a specific initial as seen below:

```
*Main> giveRaise 'A' 200 [('A',"Al",1000),('B',"Bob",1500)]
```

Which would give an answer of this:

```
[('A',"Al",1200),('B',"Bob",1500)]
```

My code so far is this, but I keep getting an error when I try it to raise initial 'g' by n:

```
giveRaise :: Char -> Int -> [(Char, String, Int)] -> [(Char, String, Int)]
giveRaise g n [(g, z, m)]
 = [(g, z, (m + n))]
```

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Thank you for your help so far, I am beginning to understand the problem better now. However, when I try the code which you have suggest, I still keep getting the error:  "Non-exhaustive patterns in function giveRaise". As I am a beginner, I don't know what this means yet. My updated code so far is: giveRaise :: Char -> Int -> [(Char, String, Int)] -> [(Char, String, Int)]
giveRaise pa n ((pb, z, m):tail)
 | pa == pb = (pb,z,m+n):tail
 | otherwise = (pb,z,m):giveRaise pa n tail

Comment: Well the problem is what you do when the person cannot be found in the list?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem In the list of tuples given, the Tuple that we are changing will always be there. Does that help at all?

Comment: can you give an example of a call where the person is in the list and it errors?

Comment: Well in my original question, the list given has "Al" in it. His initial is A and I want to raise his number from 1000 to 1200

Comment: @SyedAhamad: well If I run the code in the answer, it generates the correct result...

Comment: I still keep getting the same error when I apply your edited code. Could you confirm that you have been able to get the right output when you try the original question I posted? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: yes `[('A',"Al",1200),('B',"Bob",1500)]`. Did you *reload* the file (enter `:r`).

Comment: I did reload the file yes. When I try it, I just type in the following: *Main> giveRaise 'A' 200 [('A',"Al",1200),('B',"Bob",1500)]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are going to modify an arbitrary element in the list so worst case you will have to *loop*. Since *recursion* is the way to loop in Haskell, it is weird that you write the `giveRaise` one clause. When using recursion you always have two types of clauses:

- a *base case*: we have found the person, and give them a raise; and
- a *recursive case*: we currently have not found the person yet, and thus keep looking for it.

The base case is simple:

```
giveRaise pa n ((pb,z,m):tail) | pa == pb = (pb,z,m+n):tail
```

In Prolog you can use the same variable in the *head* and *unification* (in Erlang, equality is checked) is done. That is not allowed in Haskell. In Haskell one uses *guards* (like `| pa == pb`) to determine if the two persons are the same.

Now there is another option: `pa` is not `pb`. In the `otherwise` case, we perform recursion and search further in the list, so:

```
                               | otherwise = (pb,z,m):giveRaise pa n tail
```

Or putting the together:

```
giveRaise pa n ((pb,z,m):tail) | pa == pb = (pb,z,m+n):tail
                               | otherwise = (pb,z,m):giveRaise pa n tail
```

There is finally a last case we have to take into account: what to do if we reach the end of the list and did not found the person? We can simply ignore that and return the empty list like:

```
giveRaise _ _ [] = []
```

or we can throw an `error`:

```
giveRaise _ _ [] = error "Could not give a raise."
```

So we can implement it like:

```
giveRaise pa n ((pb,z,m):tail) | pa == pb = (pb,z,m+n):tail
                               | otherwise = (pb,z,m):giveRaise pa n tail
giveRaise _ _ [] = error "Could not give a raise."
```

Finally note that this function will **only give a raise to the first person with the given identifier**. **Not all persons with that identifier**. I however assumed that the identifiers are unique.

Comment: I think you should mention that if two persons have the same identifier `pb` in the list only the first (in list order) gets the raise.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: yeah good point. I added a note at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

"Do *something* to one element in a list" is the same as "do *something else* to every element in the list", where *something else* does *something* when the element is the one you're looking for and *nothing* when it's not. In other words, it makes sense to structure this operation as a `map`.

```
giveRaise :: Char -> Int -> [(Char, String, Int)] -> [(Char, String, Int)]
giveRaise x amt = map raise
    where raise (y, n, salary)
            | x == y    = (y, n, salary + amt)
            | otherwise = (y, n, salary)
```